# The Fermi level position does not match up with previous calculation

Tags: band-structure

I have calculated the band structure of g-C3N4 monolayer using Quantum ESPRESSO (QE). The k-points i used was 4x4x1 and the cut-off energy of 60 Ry. First, I calculated it with the Generalized Gradient Approximation (GGA) (PBE) exchange-correlation functional using the Projector Augmented-Wave (PAW) method implemented in its pseudopotential. Second, I calculated it with hybrid Heyd-Scusseria-Ernzerhof (HSE) exchange-correlation functional and the PAW method, but using coarse nqx x nqy x nqz of 1x1x1. For calculation using HSE functional, after calculating scf, I used Wannier interpolation to get the band structure. This is the band structure I got using both exchange-correlation functionals.

[image]

I got a desired band gap with HSE, which is in great agreement with experimental value of 2.7 eV. The calculation with HSE functional shows that the Fermi level is close to the conduction band, which is in agreement with the fact that g-C3N4 is an n-type semiconductor. I also compared it with [previous literature](https://doi.org/10.1039/D1TA07286B), they also used the PBE functional. In contrast, they shown that the Fermi level position is close to the top of valence band which is shown in figure below.

[image]

Which is right and which is wrong? How to overcome this problem?

Comment: Could you provide how you have defined the unit cell, this difference might be due to the vacancies.

Comment: i use the same kind of g-C3N4, which is tri-s-triazine g-C3N4